# The redundant data of facebook Pixel

Tags: shopify, facebook-pixel

Environment:

1. Set the Facebook Pixel ID in my web. (Shopify)
2. Examine my web with "Pixel Help" and there is only one Pixel Id.

Problem:

1. The data of Pixel conflicts with the real case. The number of purchase in Pixel during "all available days" is 183, while all orders of my shop are just around 80.
   [the data of Pixel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u2GJ4.jpg)
2. Each request of "Purchase" event come with a double request. (like the picture)
   [the request of "Purchase"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vROHt.jpg)

I can't see the correct data of my web because of last 2 points, please help.

Looking forward reply : ）
(I will provide more information if needed)

Comment: Where did you install the Pixel code? Through the Shopify Analytics configuration or in the code (or both)?

Comment: Shopify Analytics configuration.  I just set the pixel ID in shopify whthout any code

Comment: It looks like the Pixel is indeed firing twice, but it's doing so with different parameters for the same purchase. I could be wrong because I don't have any experience with Pixel, but other than you seeing two requests, it shouldn't affect tracking because the content_id is only in one pixel